Postfix deferred mails if 1 of many adresses is wrong
If someone sends mail from Outlook with multiple addresses in bcc and 1 of them is wrong (syntax or unknown user) mail gets deferred and no one gets it:
Sep 10 08:46:48 server postfix/qmgr[31948]: 49F66343334: from=sender@domain.de, size=157445, nrcpt=137 (queue active) Sep 10 08:47:17 server amavis[31980]: (31980-02-7) ...user1@dom1.com>,user2@dom2.com, Queue-ID: 49F66343334, Message-ID: 00c001db0050$3cfcdd70$b6f69850$@domain.hr, mail_id: 59ltGgATK09y, Hits: -2.957, size: 157975, 3513 ms
Sep 10 08:47:17 server postfix/smtp[31985]: 49F66343334: to=user1@dom1.com, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, conn_use=7, delay=328583, delays=328554/26/0/3.5, dsn=4.5.0, status=deferred (host 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1] said: 451 4.5.0 id=31980-02-7 - Temporary MTA failure on relaying, From MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025) during fwd-data-chkpnt (Bail out, DATA accepted but tempfailed recips, not an LMTP input at (eval 94) line 1185.): id=31980-02-7 (in reply to end of DATA command))
Sep 10 08:47:17 server postfix/smtp[31985]: 49F66343334: to=user2@dom2.com, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10024, conn_use=7, delay=328583, delays=328554/26/0/3.5, dsn=4.5.0, status=deferred (host 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1] said: 451 4.5.0 id=31980-02-7 - Temporary MTA failure on relaying, From MTA(smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025) during fwd-data-chkpnt (Bail out, DATA accepted but tempfailed recips, not an LMTP input at (eval 94) line 1185.): id=31980-02-7 (in reply to end of DATA command))

Debian 8.11, Postfix 2.11.3
I've searching over the internet for a solution and changing mail.cf but no progress.

What lives at 127.0.0.1:10025? It's that thing who doesn't let mails pass, not Postfix. Also, reminder, always include relevant configuration in such cases. Also, please post the complete log line, maybe even all the log lines that are relevant to this mail transaction, not just some excerpt from one of them.

Also, Debian 8.x "Jessie" is very outdated and unsupported. Upgrade.

Yes, i know, but for now it has to be that version. I think that on that port is Amavis. What config file should I attach?

Amavis's, obviously. But for this case I'm afraid it works correctly and no sane person would want to change it; you just have to make sure you don't attempt to send to undeliverable addresses, that's all. Instead of putting many addresses into BCC in Outlook, start using a proper mass mail sending machine like Mailman, it will handle all this stuff automatically. And, upgrade, it must not stay like this, it is unsafe to run non-security-patched systems in the Internet; you'll eventually get into various black lists when (not "if") someone starts exploiting your system.

I am aware of everything that you are writing, thanks.. How to fix it in a way that this batch of mail-s get where they suposed to go? And in the future, I'll do this upgrade and change metod of sending mass emails.

If you're aware of what you have to do, why are you asking and still not working on it? If you're asking of how to break your own system in a way so it would work incorrectly, sorry, ServerFault is not the right place to ask, and I won't bother to even attempt to answer. We're about reasonable management practices.
